# enumerating and deleting activemq queues using JMS client

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I desire to programatically purge all queues, either as an administrative function or during dev/test to get a clean system.

Following inline examples, I've written code like:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection)connectionFactory.createConnection();
DestinationSource destinationSource = connection.getDestinationSource();
for (ActiveMQQueue queue : destinationSource.getQueues()) {
    connection.destroyDestination(queue);
}
```

However, getQueues() always returns an empty set, even though there are queues visible in the web console.  Looking at the source code, it appears that the queues list is only populated by listening for queue-create advisory topic messages, so any queues that exist at the time this code is run are not listed.

This would seem to contradict [the ActiveMQ docs](https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-topics-and-queues-in-a-broker) where it says "As of 5.1.0 you can use the new DestinationSource on an ActiveMQConnection to access the available queues"

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better interface to enumerating and purging queues?

I am using ActiveMQ 5.15.12

This is also the topic of [a bug report I submitted](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to [manage](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx-support) Queues would be via the [JMX Mbeans](https://livebook.manning.com/book/activemq-in-action/chapter-14/58) from the broker itself that expose APIs for enumerating the Queues and for [purging](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/QueueViewMBean.html), deleting etc which a manager would want.

Another option is to use the [Jalokia](https://activemq.apache.org/rest) Rest API which is a nice layer over the JMX MBeans

There's some good docs for managing ActiveMQ via JMX just a quick Google search away.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd seen the Manning page before but was deterred by the paywall.  Seems that JMX is a good way to go.  Can you add a link to "good docs for managing ActiveMQ via JMS"?  I found nothing (unless by JMS you mean the JMX API).  I did find comments like "The JMS API does not support queue listing"

Comment: Fixed JMS to be JMX, muscle memory always causes me to type JMS.  The DestinationSource bits aren't really robust enough for real management of the broker